# Making part of a switch statement case fall through but not all?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Probably doesn't make a difference because the question is about a basic control structure but I'm writing in Javascript. (tagged as such on the off chance that it does)

I'm familiar with switch statements of the sort
`case 'foo':
 case 'bar':
     do a;
     do b;
     do c;
     break;`

Is there a way to make part of a case fall through and be applied to the next case but not all? That is, is there syntax for the switch equivalent of:

```
if(my_var == 'foo' || my_var == 'bar') do a;
if(my_var == 'foo') do b;
if(my_var == 'bar') do c;
```

I feel like it should be something common that I'm just missing because it seems a very useful idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really only the `foo` and `bar` branches that are special, and you have other branches to the `switch` as well, you can put `if` statements in a common branch for `foo` and `bar`:

```
switch (my_var) {
  case 'foo':
  case 'bar':
    do a;
    if (my_var == 'foo') do b;
    if (my_var == 'bar') do c;
    break;
  case 'other':
    do d;
    break;
  case 'more':
    do e;
    break;
  // ...and so on...
}
```

**But** that only makes sense in the abnormal case of two fundamentally similar branches in a `switch` with other, dissimilar branches.

In the normal case, [Joe Enos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25021350/157247) has the right approach: Break the logic up into small reusable bits (function call overhead [is a non-issue](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)). Do the small bits in the branches.

Comment: This makes the most sense in my case. You're right that it's an abnormal situation. Now I'm kicking myself because I did something similar a year ago!

Answer (score 2):

No, that is unfortunately not possible with normal switch statements.

A solution is for example to split it in two switch statements.

```
switch (x) {
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        a();
}

switch (x) {
    case 'foo':
        b();
        break;
    case 'bar':
        c();
}
```

Or, as Joe suggested, just repeat the function:

```
switch (x) {
    case 'foo':
        a();
        b();
        break;
    case 'bar':
        a();
        c();
}
```

Use whatever solution is shorter... It depends on the context.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that - just separate out your action into a function that can be called by any of the cases. It will make things nice and readable.

```
var funcA = function() { /* do a */ };

switch (x) {
    case 'foo':
         funcA();
         funcB();
         break;
    case 'bar':
         funcA();
         funcC();
         break;
}
```

Comment: +1 Small, reusable pieces is almost always the answer to this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
if (my_var == 'foo' || my_var == 'bar') {
  do a;
}

switch (my_var) {
   case 'foo':
     do b;
     break;
   case 'bar':
     do c;
     break;
}
```

I think this makes the logic clearest to the reader.